# Grails: Rendering JSON using executeQuery

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am testing out a controller and simply want to retrieve the JSON. However, I'm noticing that the controller returns data but it does not return the JSON properly with the key/value pairs. It literally only returns the data. I notice however, that if I use Incident.getAll(), it returns the JSON properly. For example, it will return [INCIDENTID: "Value"] as opposed to using executreQuery which just returns the data.

My code:

```
def incident = Incident.executeQuery("select a.INCIDENTID from Incident a")
render incident as JSON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from `executeQuery` is a list of the properties you specified, not actual domain objects.  For example:

```
TestDomain.executeQuery("select t.id from TestDomain") as JSON
===> [1, 2, 3]
```

If you want domain objects, you can use `findAll` instead.  Try something like this:

```
TestDomain.findAll("from TestDomain") as JSON
===>[{"class":"TestDomain","id":1,"name":"one"},
  {"class":"TestDomain","id":2,"name":"two"},
  {"class":"TestDomain","id":3,"name":"three"}]
```

Comment: Ah. That makes things clearer. So if I were to add criteria to findAll(), will it still return to me all domain objects matching the criteria?

Comment: Correct, if you add a where clause it will still return domain objects.

Comment: You can also define a named query using Hibernate Criteria API, which allows for a more complex query creation http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Comment: I have another question for you guys. I'm reading the Grails documentation and I'm seeing methods that all do similar functions. For example, when would it be appropriate to use List() vs findAll() or get() vs read()? Let me know if this should be a separate question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a bit..Like if I want to execute a query using find all with some criteria and all..how to do it?

Comment: You'd use [`findAllBy*`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) or [`findWhere`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findWhere.html)